# Activity flow issues on a multi-step wizard

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a 5-step informational wizard with back and next buttons, each step is an activity. The problem is when a user taps the back button on the activity (not the back button of the phone) then taps next again, the order of the activities is being messed up a bit. This is mostly seen when the user presses the physical back button on the phone.

Example:

> (1)(next) -> (2)(next) -> (3)(back) -> (2)(next) -> (3)(next) -> (4)

Now when the user presses the back key on the phone repeatedly from step 4, the activities will be shown in the following order:

> 4 - 3 - 2 - 3 - 2 - 1

instead of

> 4 - 3 - 2 - 1

Here's the code for my 3rd screen:

```
public class Step3Activity extends Activity {
    Button buttonNext, buttonBack;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
        buttonBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);

        buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                next();
            }
        });
        buttonBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                back();
            }
        });
    }

    private void next() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Step4Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void back() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Step2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I don't see any errors so I think it may just be something in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `back()` method as it starts another instance of the previous activity. You can just call `finish()` on the current activity and automatically go back to the previous activity if you don't need to pass data back.

```
    private void back() {
        finish();
    }
```